# Most optimized way of keeping document histories in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I need help with MongoDb and how to keep track of changes (in the most optimized way) in a document inside a specific collection. Currently the way we do it is we have 2 tables, one for the actual document (`members` table) and another one (`membersHistory`) for keeping the history, let's say we have this object in `members` table

```json
// Members table object:
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64ec7bb0b174e7eb9c98137a"
      },
      "Email": "john@gmail.com",
      "PhoneNumber": "123-123-123-123",
      "FirstName": "John",
    }
```

and we have another table named `membersHistory` where we store changes for any member from the `members` table, it looks like this

```json
// Member's history snapshot:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6506b0f4103d3d6d873e4ebd"
  },
  "TargetTable": "members",
  "TimeStamp": {
    "$date": "2023-09-17T07:55:31.681Z" // recorded time it was edited
  },
  "ActionType": "Updated",
  "PropertyPath": "PhoneNumber", // the property that was changed
  "MemberId": "64ec7bb0b174e7eb9c98137a", // the member's id we use to do $lookup
  "OldValue": "321-312-321",
  "NewValue": "123-123-123-123",
  "OriginalObjectSnapshot": { // the actual snapshot of the object before it was changed
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64ec7bb0b174e7eb9c98137a"
    },
    "Email": "john@gmail.com",
    "PhoneNumber": "321-312-321",
    "FirstName": "John"
  }
}
```

### The Problem

We used this structure for weeks now and our `members` table is growing rapidly, at the moment we have around 500K+ members and around 5M+ history documents, everytime we search for members we also have to include the member's history information in the search query like if a member's phone number was originally `321-312-321` we should be able to find that too in one search, we use `$lookup` to do this but it takes around 20+ seconds to perform the query. We're both searching from the `members` and `membersHistory` table.

Everything in the `membersHistory` object is indexed, but maybe after the $lookup and adding the said object as a field to the `members` table, the indexes are gone?

### What I've tried

I tried indexes, $text index you name it but it's just slow. I've also tried reversing the query like searching in the `membersHistory` table then doing the $lookup to `members` table but it's 5 times slower

### The Question

I've did my research and I've came up with the proposed solution below:

- Put the member and it's history in the same table, like putting some kind of versioning so that we wont have to do an expensive $lookup every search

Is this solution good for the long term? We might go as far as getting 10M+ members and just imagine the history since our staff is editing members every day, if there are other solutions please do tell!

Comment: That's is all helpful context but... what's the actual query that you're trying to run? It's hard to say what's with/slow without it which really prevents us from being in a position to advise on how to improve/fix it

Comment: Does the explain() show useful information?

Comment: @QiangFu won't be useful since I only run 2 aggregations, it says it uses COLLSCAN

Comment: @user20042973 I'm trying to do a lookup from another table containing members

Comment: Explain _would_ be helpful though because, at the very least, it would show us what queries/approach you are currently using. It's not clear to me how we are supposed to advise on how to make something better (specifically '_the most optimized way_') without knowledge about the current state. We know you tried a $text index and we know that you're currently doing a collection scan. Do standard indexes not help here? (We could say if we say the queries.) Would combining the collections result in satisfactory performance if you're doing a collection scan? Please help us help you